# How to aggregate data in order to calculate percentile in SQL?

Tags: sql, aggregation

I have a US 2016 primaries dataset, it includes state name, county, candidate name, number of votes per candidate in each county.
I want to calculate the percentile per candidate in each state. 
example of the data:

```
state   state_abbreviation  county  fips    party   candidate   votes   
0   Alabama AL  Autauga 1001    Democrat    Bernie Sanders  544 
1   Alabama AL  Autauga 1001    Democrat    Hillary Clinton 2387    
2   Alabama AL  Baldwin 1003    Democrat    Bernie Sanders  2694    
3   Alabama AL  Baldwin 1003    Democrat    Hillary Clinton 5290    
4   Alabama AL  Barbour 1005    Democrat    Bernie Sanders  222 
5   Alabama AL  Barbour 1005    Democrat    Hillary Clinton 2567    
6   Alabama AL  Bibb    1007    Democrat    Bernie Sanders  246 
7   Alabama AL  Bibb    1007    Democrat    Hillary Clinton 942
```

I tried to use partition by and group by, but for some reason, I cannot reach the right code.

```
SELECT state,
       candidate,
       100* SUM(votes) OVER (PARTITION BY Candidate, State)
        /SUM(VOTES) OVER(PARTITION BY state) as 'fraction_by_state'
FROM primary_results 
Order By state
```

The goal is to calculate the percentile of the votes per candidate for each state.

Comment: (1) How do you define "percentile per candidate"?  (2) What database are you using?

Comment: (2) DB from kaggle, https://www.kaggle.com/benhamner/2016-us-election.  (1) the sum of total votes for the candidate per state divided total votes per the same state.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the *ratio* of the vote per state, you can use aggregation and window functions:

```
SELECT state, candidate,
       SUM(votes) as num_votes,
       SUM(votes) * 1.0 / SUM(SUM(votes)) OVER (PARTITION BY state) as state_ratio
FROM primary_results 
GROUP BY state, candidate
ORDER BY state, candidate
```

Comment: The Ratio also helps me, Thank you a lot!